# Selecting all exterior angles on a 2D mesh after mesh intersection (Geometry Nodes)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a flat 2d mesh of a ring, I instance a load of cubes around the edge and mesh bool the difference for the resulting mesh:

[image]

Now I want to take the intersecting edges and filter out all of the interior angles, so I am just left with a selection of the following vertices, so I can assign a named attribute and bevel them:

[image]

I can't figure out how to filter them in geometry nodes...

Comment: Aren't these edges those with a distance from origin greater than [something] ? Maybe *Position* into *Vector Length* into *Greater than* ?

Comment: Interesting idea, but then we need to work out what is [something]? I would rather it wasn't a manual input. Also it's difficult to see but outer edges are made of many vertices because it's cut from a high resolution circle. So we need to filter these out as well and just select the vertices that form distinct outward corners. I figured there must be a way to calculate the signed angle between 2 vertices and see which ones are less than -45 degrees the inner angles would be filtered out because they'd be around positive 90.

Comment: You just have to tweak to get once the [something]. Matter of seconds. Why wouldn't you do it manually ? Is there a reason ? Does your gear model change shape or size ? Something else ? Maybe update your question with a bit more information. I'll gladly help if I can. For now, it seems super quick and easy to do (manually).

Comment: There are many models, many sizes. And like I said, there are many vertices along the circumference that your method would bevel, that I don't want to bevel. I need to bevel just the ringed vertices in my screenshot programmatically in geometry nodes.

Comment: We can't guess these models and sizes. Thus we also can't guess the "laws" to select these vertices. Provide us with more informations if you're hoping to get an answer.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.